# Mimicking the openssl call in node with another library

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptojs

I am running this openssl code to generate a token to be used to encrypt my hls stream.

```
"openssl rand 16 > '" + folder + "/master.key' && echo '" + hex + "' | xxd -r -p > '" + folder + "/master.key'"
```

The openssl library has issues on windows for I am looking for a way to mimic the above call in a different node library.

I have tried crypto with node js with the call below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
require('crypto').randomBytes(16, function(err, buffer) {
        
        var hex = buffer.toString('hex');

        console.log(hex);

});
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function hex2bin(hex){
        return new Buffer(hex, "hex");
    }

    require('crypto').randomBytes(16, function(err, buffer) {
        
        var hex = buffer.toString('hex');

        fs.writeFile(folder + "/master.key", hex2bin(hex), function (err) {



        });

    });
```

Sussed it